# How to check if a NFC recording occurred successfully

Tags: android, nfc

I need to check if my NFC writting procedure on Android was successful.

Source code:

```
// Step 1 - Writing
Ndef myNdefVar = Ndef.get(tag);
myNdefVar.writeNdefMessage(ndefMessage);
```

Sometimes, the `writeNdefMessage` method doesn't raise an exception. So I need to check the content manually:

```
// Step 2 - Checking
NdefMessage messageRead = myNdefVar.getNdefMessage();
```

However, the user can remove the tag from device between step 1 and 2, causing a wrong check of result.

Anybody have a better idea to check the result?

Comment: Have you tried catching the `TagLostException` too?

Comment: Hi @henrycjc, none exceptions was raised

Comment: If it doesn't raise an exception, then it is because it wrote successfully. I get that you feel you need to confirm this as a separate step but I would advise against it. If you don't trust the Ndef API, then note that you are just trusting it the 2nd time.

Comment: It's just for precaution. A few times, i get corrupted tags after writing process.